# ASP.NET - Creating a re-usable widget

Tags: asp.net

I am looking to create a re-usable widget that can be placed in any site. I know you can do this using a Class Library but the draw back of doing it this way is that you don't have the benefits of the UI (i.e dragging and dropping controls) and have to declare things like:

public TextBox _txt = new TextBox();

which is really boring, takes a very long time, and is un-managable for the HTML and CSS.

I've tried creating my set of controls in Visual Studio but can't seem to find a way.

So, ideally I'm looking to have a set of User controls that can be placed in other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

If you create your controls in a Class Library you don't have to declare your controls in code as you described if you add the library to your toolbox directly instead of adding the library as a reference. Try it out, I have done it this way countless times.

Good luck!

Comment: But this would involve me creating the classes just using the C# code and not having the benefits of just dragging and dropping the controls and wrapping them with html etc

Comment: People who use notepad to develop aren't developers considering there are tools such as visual studio to help.

Answer (score 0):

A [private NuGet repository](http://www.chrispont.co.uk/2011/09/creating-a-private-nuget-repository-and-creating-packages/) might be an interesting solution?